# How to change display time android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I do enjoy Android Studio and especially its FullScreen view which allows me to dive deeper into code. And when hover mouse into top-right corner of screen - it shows me time. And for some reason it shows wrong time! Does anybody know HOW to change it?

[image]

It was actually hard to make a proof :D So i had to make a screenshot and put it into paint and then use Scissors)

Comment: For clarification: Can you confirm (possibly with a screenshot, tu illustrate the issue) that the time displayed by Android Studio is different from the system time as displayed by your OS?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper done. It's going ahead for 1 hour

Comment: Maybe you need to report it to Google and wait for upgrade. By the way, It doesn't  shows in MacOS.